# Installing kde-runtime on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: software-installation, kde, 19.10, kdenlive

I want to compile kdenlive from source, and one of its dependencies is the package kde-runtime.

This package does not [exist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kde-runtime&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) in the repository for ubuntu 19.10, which I am running, but it does for 19.04.

How do I install this package on my system?

Comment: The package `kde-runtime` contained Qt4 components; Qt5 came out in 2012 & all packages that still needed Qt4 are now removed (from Debian/Ubuntu), as they had years to be upgraded to use Qt5 only (*the same is happening elsewhere too; being announced years ago*).

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to install one the pre-packaged versions shipped by the kdenlive developers? I see Appimage, Flatpack and snap mentioned here: https://kdenlive.org/en/download/ My personal choice would be the AppImage package: https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/kdenlive-19.12.1-x86_64.appimage

Answer (score 0):

1. First install `kde-plasma-desktop`. Note: This is a heavy package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
   ```
2. (Optional) Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kde-runtime
   ```